# Docker Pull Error - json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type string

Tags: docker, pull

I'm trying to pull my image from private docker repo (hosted by Artifactory 3.9.1)
Installed latest docker and docker-machine 1.8.3
I'm always getting the following error:

```
Boot2Docker version 1.8.3, build master : af8b089 - Mon Oct 12 18:56:54 UTC 2015
Docker version 1.8.3, build f4bf5c7
docker@dev:~$ 
docker@dev:~$ docker pull private-repo.com:5555/namespace/tag
Using default tag: latest
Pulling repository private-repo.com:5555/namespace/tag
json: cannot unmarshal number into Go value of type string
```

Could somebody help solving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Scott Herzinger who helped finding the solution

Here is some info on a problem that sounds related. It occurs with Docker versions 1.8.x. It is fixed in Artifactory 3.9.2. Your Artifactory version is 3.9.1.

https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-7628?jql=text%20~%20%22docker%20unmarshal%20json%22

A possible workaround might be to use Docker version 1.7.x